# Using Headless FireFox to Save All HTML files using command line in Linux

Tags: shell, firefox, headless

Using shell_exec with Xvfb and FireFox currently to capture screen shots.  However, need to download the entire html (e.g. Save Page As --> Web Page complete.) to a directory using shell_exec.  Have looked at all the different option available in the Mozilla Developers Forums but have not been able to figure out how to do this.

This code appears to be what I might need but where and how is this implemented so it can be accessible in shell_exec?

```
var file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"]
.createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
file.initWithPath("C:\\filename.html");
var wbp = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/embedding/browser/nsWebBrowserPersist;1']
.createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIWebBrowserPersist);
wbp.saveDocument(content.document, file, null, null, null, null);
```

[The Above Code Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/Miscellaneous)

```
void saveDocument(
in nsIDOMDocument aDocument,
in nsISupports aFile,
in nsISupports aDataPath,
in string aOutputContentType,
in unsigned long aEncodingFlags,
in unsigned long aWrapColumn
);
```

[The Above Code Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsILocalFile)

There is a Stackoverflow manual solution here but it does not address shell_exec:
[How to save a webpage locally including pictures,etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271898/how-to-save-a-webpage-locally-including-pictures-etc)

Answer (score 1):

There are few options that I know of, but none that I know are fitting your question exactly..

1. Open `firefox http://yoursite.com` from shell, then send keystrokes to firefox using `xte` or similar method. (This is not headless mode though.)
2. Download using wget. It can work in recursive manner. Or alternately you can parse the HTML, if it is quite simple web page. If you need to submit form, use curl instead of wget.
3. Use greasemonkey addon & write a script, which would get loaded on `http://some-fake-page.com/?download=http://yoursite.com` & then open firefox with that fake-page url.
4. Develop your own firefox addon to do above work.

There may be other better options for this as well, but I don't know them.

Comment: Thanks.  I think your number three answer might be the key. And, how or what does the Mozilla provided code snippets do, (My Example One)?  They have several of these but no explanation of what to do with them. Your answer three may be the way to use these directly.

Comment: I am not sure, if you can use mozilla code snippets directly from a greasemonkey script. (But I may be wrong.) They can be directly used from a custom addon. However, GM does provide a wrapper function to use some of the mozilla APIs