# How can I use `localStorage` to store an entire page?

Tags: javascript, html

I've been reading the book *HTML in action* and in chapter 5, it shows how to create a mobile application that can be run offline. My only doubt is: can I do this for an entire page? Can you give me a simple, but complete, example on how to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look into this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271898/how-to-save-a-webpage-locally-including-pictures-etc

Comment: Look into [AppCaching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache).

Comment: for an entire page you should use a manifest file. not the local storage, it is too small.

Comment: Oh, how can I do it? @ maboiteaspam 21, Sorry for my dumbness, I'm new to HTML5, I'm still learning :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Kinda crazy but you could do it like so:

```
var htmlContents = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
localStorage.setItem('myBook', JSON.stringify(htmlContents ));
```

From there you can call it up whenever you like..

```
localStorage.getItem('myBook');
```

It would be better of course to get the actually book contents of course instead of the entire page!

Also as for what you want to do with this later. Well its only in your browser.. so its accessible only to you. 
for the appCahce method, basically you will be telling the visiting browser of the files you wish to store in the cache so they are available when the user is offline.

This needs to be defined in the `HTML` attribute:

```
<html manifest="offline_book.manifest">
```

This `offline_book.manifest` will contain the file list to store in the cache.

```
CACHE MANIFEST
/book_index.html
/another_book.html
/maybe_some_style.css
```

Through this, then when the users come back to this page (**offline**), they will have a cached version of the books you have listed.

An excellent resource into the `appCache` specifics: [Offline Webpages](http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html)

Comment: Would the user be able to load the entire page offline?

Comment: If you stored javascript in their cache that could retrieve it on load, then yes certainly, but most likely the `appCaching` is the better option for your situation.

Comment: Could you make an example using app cache, I will mark it as the answer immediately :)

Comment: Ill add an example now, its quite simple.

Comment: @Calne as you can see from the example, there is no black magic, just a notifier telling the browser what needs to be available offline!

Comment: Oh yeah, I see it, I'm going to try it, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For example you can use `localStorage` for saving variable:

```
// Store
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```

and get it after:

```
localStorage.getItem('lastname');
```

**window.localStorage** implemented follow interface which [accepted by W3C](https://w3c.github.io/webstorage/#storage-0):

```
interface Storage {
  readonly attribute unsigned long length;
  [IndexGetter] DOMString key(in unsigned long index);
  [NameGetter] DOMString getItem(in DOMString key);
  [NameSetter] void setItem(in DOMString key, in DOMString data);
  [NameDeleter] void removeItem(in DOMString key);
  void clear();
};
```

More information you can read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying how to use 'localStorage' +1 :)