# Storing the whole content of any website from a script?

Tags: javascript, html, tampermonkey, html5-appcache

I'm working on a script that I run with Tampermonkey and I would like to add an option for offline navigation. The script is prepared to work with any website and is related to Web Adaptation.

First of all, I've tried to set the manifest attribute from the script but I'm not sure if that is possible. Since I have no way to add new files to the websites, I'm not able to use a local `.manifest` file. Is there any way to achieve something like this:

```
    var a = document.getElementsByTagName("html");
    a.setAttribute("manifest", "CACHE MANIFEST URL1, URL2, URLn");
```

The other way I thought to manage this situation was using localStorage instead but the size of it is really small. 
(Seen this [How can I use `localStorage` to store an entire page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30847063/how-can-i-use-localstorage-to-store-an-entire-page))

Any ideas?