# javascript save html from a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, save

I'm new into javascript.

When I enter https://www.yahoo.com/ it is possible to right click and save the HTML is this also possible from a javascript.

I would like just to run a javascript on my local machine, press a bottom that will save the html from https://www.yahoo.com/.
I do not want to show the https://www.yahoo.com/ on my local machine, just saving the html file so I can open the file locally.

Is this possible and how do I do this in javascript

Br Bo

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271898/how-to-save-a-webpage-locally-including-pictures-etc

Answer (score -2):

Yes, You can save the Webpage by right click and save the HTML. Make sure to have format 'Webpage, Complete' while saving the page. You will get the HTML page eg: index.html along with a folder having all the assets (js, css..). Now you can write your own javaScript and any more things you need.

[file format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/as19I.png)